# How do I view all the questions & answers I follow?

Tags: support, follow-posts

I think this feature was added quite recently but is there any way I can view all the questions I am currently following?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)...

> We are still planning on two more related releases:
>
> 1. **Follows profile tab and question listing filter**: A tab for follows will be added to your user profile activity page. Each user will be able to view this tab that will provide a listing of followed questions and answers, with standard sorts, and the ability to unfollow from the listing. Users (with the exception of moderators and authorized staff) will not be able to see this information about other users (nor will it be made public in the API, SEDE, or data dumps). Additionally a filter in the [more] drop down on the Questions listing page will be added for Followed.

So just wait for that release.

Comment: hope this feature gets added ASAP

Comment: i'm suprised something like this wasn't in the mvp.

Comment: I'll have to follow this to know the status-completed :)

Comment: I just hope we’ll get some search filter that we can negate, so I can search for `⟨interesting topic⟩ notfavoritedby:me` or something to get to all the posts I haven’t followed yet.

Comment: Oh no, the [search filter proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345684/289905) has been [tag:status-declined]…

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, you can see your followed posts in your profile page (Activity tab)

[image]