# Get access to the followed post

Tags: support, feature-request

Recently, I have use the follow button to keep track on some questions, I do not know when this function has been existed, but I just saw a pop to suggest me to use the follow feature. Hence, I have used it, instead of using favourite. Currently, I want to have a look on the posts I followed, after searching here and there, I got nowhere to access.

Answer (score -1):

I also saw this feature today morning and when I used this, it gives the notification that you will get notified when there would be an activity on the post- That means if someone answers the question, or the OP accepts an answer, you would be notified.

But there is no indication that you have saved the question for later reference, for that purpose, **please Favourite the question**!

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395914/9819031), this would be added soon. So just wait for the release!